# Is there a way to average specific ranges from a 2D matrix using an index value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several matrixes that are 5 columns by 30 rows where data is sequential from row-to-row from left to right.

Example of ordering

[image]

I am looking to be able to average specific ranges from that data based on an index. For example, I'd like the averages of:

- The first 6 values (yellow)
- The next 3 values (green)
- The next 2 values (blue)
- The next 4 values (orange)

[image]

In my mind, one way to go about that is to flatten the array to a 2D vector, and then use something like an `=average(offset(reference,X,0,Y,1))`, where:

[image: Example of Vector]

- X would be the number of rows to skip in the vector
- Y would be the row size of values I want to average

Is there some way to use offset, or some other Excel function to treat a matrix like a 2D vector and extract averages based on an index asking for the first X number of values, then the next Y, next Z, .... etc. values?

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 2016 we will need to create a 1D array from the 2D array.  We can do that with INDEX using MOD and INT to get the correct values based on the inputs of start and end.

```
=AVERAGE(
    INDEX(A1:E3,
        N(IF({1},INT((ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,H1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,H2))-1)/5)+1)),
        N(IF({1},MOD(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,H1):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,H2))-1,5)+1))))
```

`H1` holds the start index and `H2` the end index.  Make sure to replace the `A1:E3` with your range of the data set.  the use of `ZZ` is arbitrary as we only care about the row numbers being returned.  I use it because it usually is empty and will not cause a unneeded calc if the data changes.

With older versions this may require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

For those with Office 365 or later we can use TOCOL and SEQUENCE:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:E3,
    st,H1,
    end,H2,
    AVERAGE(INDEX(TOCOL(rng),SEQUENCE(end-st+1,,st))))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me right now on my copy of Excel 2013 and Excel 2016 that I have when I tried replicating your screenshot. The formula matches what you posted, and I tried manually typing what your screenshot displayed in the formula bar as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdHP0.png

Comment: maybe you need to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Click in the formula bar on that cell then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @user3832265 actually see edit.  Use the edited formula and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  I forget the hoops we need to jump through for the older versions.